# Variable in component gets updated only after second function call in service in angular 4

Tags: angular, typescript, http

I am new to Angular framework. I was developing a basic data retrieval from component via service. I had already developed web service which spits out certain data for id(`wwid`). Function called via service(`app.service`) through component (`queueSearch.component`) initiates a `GET` request. The data is successfully retrieved within service however it does not update the variable associated with component (`waittime`) immediately. Variable only gets updated after second call (basically click the search button twice to update it on html). How could I update it in single click?

**app.service.ts**

```
searchWWID(wwid: number)
{
  console.log("from app service wwid: " + wwid.toString());
  this.http.get("http://localhost:3000/api/list/" + wwid).subscribe(Data =>{
     if(Data != null)
     {
       this.waitingTime = JSON.stringify(Data)
     }
     else
     {
       this.waitingTime = "";
     }
     //this gets updated instantaneously and prints 
     console.log(this.waitingTime);
    });
   return this.waitingTime;
  }
}
```

**queueSearch.component.ts**

```
searchWWID()
{
  if(isNaN(Number(this.wwid)))
  {
    console.log("not a number");
  }
 else
 {
   if(this.wwid.toString().length !== 8)
   {
     console.log("should be eight digits")
   }
   else
   { 
     //this(waittime) only gets updated after every second call to this function
     this.waitTime =  this.AppService.searchWWID(Number(this.wwid))
   }
  }
}
```

**queueSearch.component.html**

```
 <h1>{{title}}</h1>
 <div style ="text-align:center">
 <form>
 <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="enter wwid" 
 [(ngModel)]="wwid" name="wwid" id="searchWWID">
 <button class="btn btn-primary" id="submitButton" 
 (click)=searchWWID()>Submit</button>
 </form>
 </div>
 <h2>waiting time: {{waitTime}}</h2>
```

Expected result: Update `waittime` in html instantaneously after `searchWWID()` call.

Actual result: `waittime` is updated after every second function call

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, the reason the Service call is not working as you expect:

```
class Service {
    constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}

    waitingTime: string;

    searchWWID(wwid: number): string
    {
        // 1. first, you create the request
        this.http
            .get('http://localhost:3000/api/list/' + wwid)
            .subscribe(Data => {
                if (Data != null) {
                    this.waitingTime = JSON.stringify(Data);
                } else {
                    this.waitingTime = '';
                }
                console.log(this.waitingTime);
            });
        // 2. then you return the waiting time
        return this.waitingTime;
        // 3. 500ms later...
        // 4. you actually get the response and `this.waitingTime` is set
        //    but unfortunately you have already returned
        // 5. not to worry: the next time you call this function,
        //    it will return the result we have just received at "step 2" above
    }
}
```

Since you are dealing with an asynchronous result, you should use a `Promise` or an `Observable` to return the result. Considering that the `http.get` function returns an observable, we will use `Observable`:

```
import {HttpClient} from '@angular/common/http';
import {Observable} from 'rxjs';
import {map, tap} from 'rxjs/operators';

class Service {

    constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}

    searchWWID(wwid: number): Observable<string>
    {
        return this.http
            .get('http://localhost:3000/api/list/' + wwid)
            .pipe(
                // use a `map` for transformation
                map(data => data !== null ? JSON.stringify(data) : ''),
                // use a `tap` for a side-effect
                tap(idString => console.log(idString)),
            );
    }
}
```

Now that the service call returns `Observable<string>`, all we need to do is use it in the component code:

```
class Component {
    constructor(private appService: Service) {}

    wwid: string;

    searchWWID(): void
    {
        // let's use "early return" to remove extra nesting
        if (isNaN(Number(this.wwid))) {
            console.log('not a number');
            return;
        }

        if (this.wwid.toString().length !== 8) {
            console.log('should be eight digits');
            return;
        }

        this.appService
            .searchWWID(Number(this.wwid))
            .subscribe((result: string) => this.wwid = result);
    }
}
```

There is a small problem with the above code, however. If you use `subscribe` inside your component code, you should remember to unsubscribe at some point (most likely when the component is destroyed).

One way to achieve that is to store the subscription in a property and manually unsubscribe using the `onDestroy` hook:

```
import {OnDestroy} from '@angular/core';
import {Subscription} from 'rxjs';

class Component implements OnDestroy {
    constructor(private appService: Service) {}

    wwid: string;
    wwidSubscription: Subscription;

    searchWWID(): void
    {
        // let's use "early return" to remove extra nesting
        if (isNaN(Number(this.wwid))) {
            console.log('not a number');
            return;
        }
        if (this.wwid.toString().length !== 8) {
            console.log('should be eight digits');
            return;
        }
        this.wwidSubscription = this.appService.searchWWID(Number(this.wwid))
            .subscribe((result: string) => this.wwid = result);
    }

    ngOnDestroy() {
        this.wwidSubscription.unsubscribe();
    }
}
```

**update**

As suggested in the comments, since our operation is a "one off thing", i.e. we get the response once, we can get away with using `take(1)`, which will kindly complete the observable for us and unsubscribe the subscribers.

Moreover, the methods in the Http module such as `get`,`post` et al, automatically complete once the request has finished, so in this case we don't really have to do anything, depending on how much you prefer to leak the details of your service into your component.

Comment: Nice work of helping the topic starter to improve his code. It's also possible to use the `take` pipleable operator to unsubscribe after `x` amount of emissions. So if you would use `take(1)` you would automatically unsubscribe after each method invocation. It might be more efficient than waiting until the component is destroyed?

Comment: @enf0rcer absolutely! I don't know why I even suggested doing the onDestroy thing :)

Comment: @enf0rcer Thanks for the answer!. However I also tried a workaround , I added a manual delay of 200 ms between the subscribe and return. How good of a workaround is this? and how accepted method it would be for future similar scenarios?

Comment: @AnugrahKumar a workaround like that is something I can only imagine using as a last resort during some sort of testing where I am not able to stub out some process, and I cannot manage the asynchronicity through a `Promise` or an `Observable`. E.g. having to wait until a driver sets up a browser to do testing for you, and somehow it's not all hidden behind a convenient promise or a hook.

Comment: @AnugrahKumar So, in other words, I would not use this "hack" unless I absolutely had no choice, as managing async processes is much more maintainable with promises/observables. Therefore, for future similar scenarios I would just stick with simple observable operations. Most of the time you can get away with knowing 4-5 rxjs operators, and it will be helpful in the long run.

Answer (score 0):

In your `queueSearch.component.ts` do this

```
 else { 
     //this(waittime) only gets updated after every second call to this function
     this.waitTime =  this.AppService.searchWWID(Number(this.wwid));                           
      console.log(this.waitTime); // check whether the value is getting update here .
// If yes, then its a matter of dirtyChecking
//Inject changedetectorref in your constructor an use that ref below.
 this.cdr.markForCheck();

}
```

Comment: could you elaborate more regarding this

Comment: No the console.log(this.waitTime) only gets updated everysecond time as well. My assumption the reason could be since subscribe is async thus waittime value is returned before updating and updating happens afterwards thus if next time is function is called the value shows up as its updated now. If somehow return is only proceeded after subscribe completes

Comment: Actually for the reason of updating  only, we are using ChangeDetectorRef so that angular forces itself to evaluate the `this.waitTime`. And your return is outside of subscribe, it doesn't even has to wait for observable to complete. Additionally, http observable automatically completes itself once the response is received.  If you have stackblitz version it might be more helpful.

Comment: Actually found a work around, I added a delay between the request.